# How to reference SQL snippet multiple times in a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to convert some stored procs to views and the stored procs have a lot of `DECLARE` statements which create constants that get referenced later in the query. For example

`SELECT @FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01')`

I need to refer to `@FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR` in a single query multiple times, what's the best way to do this without having to declare variables?

For example consider:

```
DECLARE @FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR datetime = DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01')
select
    @FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR as FirstDayLastYear,
    Case when orderDate > @FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR then 'CurrentOrders' else 'ArchiveOrders' end as State
from
    orders
```

I don't want to rewrite as

```
select
    DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01') as FirstDayLastYear,
    Case when orderDate > DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01') then 'CurrentOrders' else 'ArchiveOrders' end as State
from
    orders
```

I want to be able to alias `@FIRSTDAYLASTYEAR` somehow in the query.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies, do you think this would perform the same:

```
select
    constants.FirstDayLastYear,
    Case when orderDate > constants.FirstDayLastYear then 'CurrentOrders' else 'ArchiveOrders' end as State
from
    orders o
cross join 
    (select 
        DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01') as FirstDayLastYear
        ) as constants
```

Reason I ask is that this code may get ported to another database platform at a future date that doesn't support CTEs.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - because views have to be a single `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a CTE that contains a single row with all of your variables, and then reference that in the query:

```
WITH Consts as (
    SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19010101', getdate()), '19000101')
           as FirstDayLastYear,
           DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19010101', getdate()), '19001231')
           as LastDayLastYear
)
select
    c.FirstDayLastYear,
    Case when orderDate > c.FirstDayLastYear then 'CurrentOrders' else 'ArchiveOrders' end as State
from
    orders
       cross join
    Consts c
```

If you have variables that build on top of other variables, you might need to have multiple levels of CTEs.

Comment: You win - I was just a bit too slow ;-)

Comment: Would there be a performance improvement if you would replace the `CROSS JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN ON 1 = 1`?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - shouldn't make a difference. `CROSS JOIN` is clear and explicit that I'm not trying to relate the next table to the previous one(s).

Comment: @MarkAllison - CTEs are part of standard SQL. If you port to another platform that doesn't support them, you're going to have plenty of other issues (e.g. around `DATEDIFF` *not* being standard)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, actually the target platform does support that (Amazon Redshift), but my question is more along the lines of performance. Is it just as valid to use a CROSS JOIN directly instead of a CTE?

Comment: @MarkAllison - I wouldn't expect a performance difference that was *measurable*. Don't try to achieve good performance by guessing or learning "the best way" to do things - set goals, measure performance, concentrate your efforts on areas where the code doesn't meet the goals.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `APPLY VALUES`:

```
SELECT   
  FirstDateLastYear as FirstDayLastYear,
  CASE WHEN orderDate > FirstDateLastYear THEN 'CurrentOrders' ELSE 'ArchiveOrders' END AS State
FROM orders
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01'))) AS date(FirstDateLastYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider 'common table expressions' like

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, getdate())), '1901-01-01') as FirstDayLastYear) 
)
SELECT Case when orderDate > FirstDayLastYear) then 'CurrentOrders' else 'ArchiveOrders' end as State
... --- your actual select statement for the view ...
FROM orders, vars
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are not allowed in views in SQL Server.
In the case you described, I would probably create a view to encapsulate the value of the variable used in the stored procedure, and then query that view as a sub query or derived table (depending on your needs) inside the bigger view.

However, this may not be possible for converting all the local variables in your stored procedure. for the cases where it's impossible, you can create a user defined function to encapsulate the value of the local variable and use it in the same way I've descried using the view.

you could create a `cte` instead of a view, however if you will need the same logic to apply to more then one view, you will have to write the `cte` for each procedure you convert to view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnPrevYear ( )
RETURNS date
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '1901-01-01', DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())), '1901-01-01')
    END
```

and just call it where needed:

```
SELECT dbo.fnPrevYear()
```

But it will be slow for large data. You can use common table expressions as a better alternative to this.